# fortran subroutine: array of arbitrary type

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to write a subroutine to reverse the rows of an array.   The following works, but explicitly declares the type of its input arr.  Thus I'd need a separate subroutine to do the same thing for an array of type real.  Surely there's a way to make it accept an array of arbitrary type - could someone help me with the syntax?  Thanks!

```
SUBROUTINE flipud(arr)

    integer, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: arr
    integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: tmp
    integer i, j, nrow, ncol, ierr

    nrow = size(arr, 1)
    ncol = size(arr, 2)

    allocate(tmp(nrow, ncol), STAT=ierr)

    tmp(:,:) = arr(nrow:1:-1, :)
    arr = tmp
    deallocate(tmp)

END SUBROUTINE flipud
```

Comment: I would just use the expression `arr = arr(nrow:1:-1, :)`

Comment: Agreed. Why introduce an extra layer of abstraction for such a simple task.

Comment: @VladimirF , point taken. You can probably tell Fortran isn't my strong suit.  I was actually doing it that way and it wasn't working and I wondered if the syntax didn't work the way I thought it did.  (This is actually part of a larger problem in which I'm parsing an ascii file but it's ending up upside down or transposed or something and I'm trying to debug; that must have been caused by a different problem...)  Anyway, thanks; I've made the change.

Comment: If you're reading the elements of an array one at a time don't be surprised if Fortran fills the array column-by-column rather than row-by-row.  And perhaps next time ask a question about what your problem really is, rather than about fixing a solution to it.

Comment: To everyone who responded: thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you would like to request Fortran committee to add template feature to the new Fortran standard, please fill out this poll: 
https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/7BTF5K8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran does not have the equivalent of C++ templates. You can create an interface with module procedures, as sketched below. The code that is common to both subroutines could be placed in a file that is incorporated using the INCLUDE statement.

```
module foo
interface fliupud
   module procedure flipud_i,flipud_r
end interface flipud

contains
subroutine flipud_i(arr)
integer, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: arr
! body
end subroutine flipud_i
!
subroutine flipud_r(arr)
real, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: arr
! body
end subroutine flipud_r
end module foo
```

Comment: Yes, but why ?  And what would you suggest for `body` that @VladimirF's comment above doesn't already encompass ?